# Function for absolute value of list elements in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, absolute

I am trying to create an R function that converts any negative values in a list of values to be positive:

```r
x <- c(5,-8,11)


abs_function <- function(A){
  n <- nrow(A)
  for (i in n) {
    if (A[i,]<0) {-A}
    else if (A[i,]>0) {A}
  }
  return(A)
}
```

But when I try:

```
abs_tfn(x)
```

it returns:

```r
[1]  5 -8 11
```

hence value -8 does not convert to 8.

Am I missing something basic here?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You have to assign: `if(A[i, ] < 0) { A[i, ] <- -A[i, ] }`. Also `for i in 1:n`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Getting this when I enter i in 1:n = Error in 1:n : argument of length 0

Comment: Sorry, the parenthese: `for(i in 1:n)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a default function for this for a *vector*: `abs()`, so you can do `abs(x)`.

For a list `x <- list(5, -8, 11)`, something like the following works:

```
fun <- function(list) {
  for (i in 1:length(list)) {
    list[[i]] <- abs(list[[i]])
  }
  return(list)
}

fun(x)
```